Probability of all sets overlapping in M sets of integers randomly drawn without replacement from 1..N
Problem:
Consider sets of $k$ integers chosen from $1..N$ without replacement. Take $M$ such sets, what is the probability what is the probability that the intersection of all the sets in the collection is empty?
$N \approx 1e20$, $k \approx 1e10$ and $M \approx 1$.

Not sure the problem is clear.  When you refer to "any pair of sets" I assume you mean "given any two distinct subsets in your collection".  Thus, the complement of that event would not be "all the sets are disjoint".  Please edit your question for clarity.  Specifically:  are you asking "what is the probability that the intersection of all the sets in the collection is empty?" or are you asking "what is the probability that there is at least one pair of disjoint sets in the collection?"

Thanks, yeah it was "what is the probability that the intersection of all the sets in the collection is empty?". I've edited the question to clarify.

Then this should be a duplicate.  I won't close the question as a duplicate (yet) because I haven't looked at the answers on the other post.  Also, at a glance, the answers aren't terribly enlightening...perhaps that is inevitable, but perhaps not.

@lulu:  given the parameters this question allows some approximations that the other one did not.

@RossMillikan agreed.  Glad i didn't close it.

Hi, I'm really sorry but I must have been too tired yesterday. I got the answer to the clarification wrong, I actually want to know the probability of $ \forall i \forall j \quad M_i \cap M_j = \phi $, or "for all pairs of sets the intersection of the pair is empty" @RossMillikan since you've already given such a nice answer should I open a new question?

I think it should be a new question

I gave the answer for $M=2$.  If you have more sets I believe the probability of intersection will be the same and independent for each pair.  In this model the probability of no match will be $e^{-M(M-1)\lambda/2}$  It will get small rapidly with $M$

I opened a new question here and accepted this answer for this one.
@RossMillikan I don't think $e^{-M(M-1)\lambda/2}$ can be the answer to the new question because the probability of any pair of sets overlapping must go up as we add more sets. I think the problem is that I picked bad notation for my comment above, maybe the new question is clearer?

The two $M$s in the exponent reflect that you are adding more sets.  I am claiming that once you know the chance that you succeed in not having an intersection in one pair of sets you need all the pairs to succeed so you raise the success probability to the power of the number of pairs.

@RossMillikan Yeah I see now, you're right. Thanks again!

With your parameters the chance of any element being in the intersection is quite small for $M \gt 2$.  The chance of more than one element being in the intersection is so small we can ignore it.  That lets us calculate the chance of one particular element being in the intersection and multiply by the number of elements.  This would give us an overcount if we had cases with more than one element in common.
The chance a particular element is in a given subset is $\frac kN$, so the chance it is in all the subsets is $\left( \frac kN \right)^M$. Multiplying by the number of elements we get $\frac {k^M}{N^{M-1}}$.  For your parameters this is $1e-10$ for $M=3$ and falls quickly.
For $M=1$ the probability is $1$.  For $M=2$ the probability of no match is $\frac {N-k \choose k}{N \choose k}=\frac {(N-k)!^2}{N!(N-2k)!}$.  When $k \approx \sqrt N$ as you have you expect this to be a reasonably sized number as in the birthday paradox.  You have about $\frac 12k^2$ tries at a probability of $\frac 1N$ of matching.  You can use Stirling's approximation on the factorials but probably need to use the next term in the expansion as well.  Probably a good approximation is to see it as a Poisson process with each possible match being independent, which is not the case but should not be far wrong.  In that case $\lambda=\frac {k^2}{2N}$ and the chance of no match is $e^{-\lambda}$
