Probability of any pairwise overlaps in $M$ sets of integers randomly drawn without replacement from $1, \ldots, N$
Problem:
Consider sets of $k$ integers chosen from $1..N$ without replacement. Take a collection $\mathbb{S} = \{s_1, \ldots, s_M\}$ of $M$ such sets, what is the probability that:
$$ \forall i \in 1, \ldots, M \quad \forall j \in 1, \ldots, M \quad s_i \cap s_j = \phi $$
$N = O(10^{20})$, $k = O(10^{10})$ and $M = O(1)$.

My attempt:
For the first set in the collection we have $N \choose k$ options, the second has $N-k \choose k$ options, $N-2k \choose k$ options, etc. So the number of ways of choosing M non-overlapping sets is:
$$\prod_{i=1}^M {N - ik \choose k}$$
The total number of all ways of choosing M sets is:
$$ {N \choose k}^{M} $$
So
$$ P = \prod_{i=1}^M \dfrac{{N - ik \choose k}}{{N \choose k}} $$
This is not feasible to compute for $N \approx 1e20$, but since $1e20 - 1e10 = 1e20 + O(1e10)$ we can ignore the $-ik$ part and everything cancels down to $P = 1$ (so $P=0$) with an error of $O(1e10)/O(1e20) = O(1e-10)$.

The part I'm least certain about here is the error term. Can we really pull the error out of the choose operation like that, or is the error bound actually much larger?
Is there a better approximation that I can use here?

Related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4994929/probability-of-all-sets-overlapping-in-m-sets-of-integers-randomly-drawn-without because I made a mistake in the initial question.

You may have an off-by-one issue in your final product.  Since overlaps are impossible when you only draw once, perhaps $P = \prod\limits_{i=1}^{M} \dfrac{{N - (i-1)k \choose k}}{{N \choose k}}$ or $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{M-1} \dfrac{{N - ik \choose k}}{{N \choose k}}$.
It is possible to compute this, for example with $M=1,2,3,4,5$ and $N=10^{20}$ and $k=10^{10}$, the probabilities, using R, are
N <- 10^20
k <- 10^10
M <- 1:5
exp(cumsum(lchoose(N-(M-1)*k, k) - lchoose(N, k)))

# 1.0000000000 0.3678906681 0.0497885878 0.0024789035 0.0000454027

Because $k=\sqrt{N}$ in this particular example, the probabilities are not far from $e^{0},e^{-1}, e^{-3}, e^{-6}, e^{-10}$
x <- c(0,1,3,6,10)
exp(-x)
# 1.0000000 0.3678794 0.004978707 0.002478752 0.00004.539993


@leonboy gave an approximation in a deleted answer with $n \gg k \gg M$ of $\exp \left(-\frac{M (M-1) k^2}{2(n-k)}\right)$

Ah I think I see, so you rearranged things into exp(log(...)) to avoid floating point overflow and use a function which computes an approximation to comb? I'll give that a try, thanks!

@dshepherd Yes:  In R choose(6,2) gives ${6 \choose 2}=15$ and lchoose(6,2) gives its logarithm $\log_e(15) \approx  2.70805$.  So lchoose(10^20,10^10) gives $240258509286.47$ corresponding to the impractical  ${10^{20} \choose 10^{10}}\approx 1.5 \times 10^{104342944813}$

Edited. You can skip the probabilistic approach and go directly to the third answer (final update)

Let $i=1, 2 \cdots  L $, with $L=\frac{M(M-1)}{2}$, index all the pairs.
Let $A_i$ be the event that the pair $i$ has no common elements. Then
$$P(A_i) = \frac{\binom{n-k}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}} \tag 1$$
For $n\gg k$ this can be approximated (see here, last asymptotics) as  $$P(A_i)\approx \left(\frac{n-2k}{n-k}\right)^k  \approx \exp \left(-\frac{k^2}{n-k}\right) \tag 2$$
The event of interest is then
$$P( \cap A_i) \approx P(A_i)^L \approx  \left(\frac{n-2k}{n-k}\right)^{kL} \approx \exp \left(-\frac{M (M-1)}{2}\frac{k^2}{n-k}\right) \tag 3$$
The first $\approx$ comes from assuming that the events $A_i$ are independent (which is not true, but should be almost true for large $n$). The second, from $(2)$.
In your case, where $n \sim k^2$ this gives $P(A_i) \approx e^{-1}=0.36788\cdots$

An approximately equivalent derivation:
Let $X_{i,j}$, $i=1 .. n$ , $j=1..M$ be the indicator variable of the event "integer $i$ got included in set $j$". Then $P(X_{i,j}=1) = k/n$.
Let $Y_i = \sum_j X_{i,j}$ count in how many sets the integer $i$ appeared.
We are interested in the event $E = \cap(E_i)$ where $E_i \equiv (Y_i\le 1)$
Because $Y_i$ is a Binomial $(M,p)$ with $p=k/n$ , $$P(E_i) = \left(1- p\right)^M + M p\left(1- p\right)^{M-1} = (1-p)^M \left(1 + M \frac{p}{1-p}\right)\approx  1 - L p^2 \tag 4$$
where $L=\frac12 M (M-1)$ and $p \to 0$.
Now, $P(E)= P(E_1) P(E_2|E_1)P(E_3|E_2 E_1) \cdots P(E_n|E_{n-1}\cdots)$
The events $E_i$ are not independent, but for $n$ large we can assume they approximately are. Then
$$P(E) \approx P(E_i)^n \approx (1 - L p^2)^n \approx \exp \left(-\frac{M (M-1)}{2}\frac{k^2}{n}\right) \tag 5$$
Again, this should be valid for $n \to \infty$, $k/n \to 0$ and fixed $M$.
And because actually $P(E_i|E_{i-1}\cdots) \le P(E_i)$ we'd expect that $(5)$ is greater than the exact value.

For example, for $k=10^{10}$, $n=k^2$, and $M=4$ both approximations $(3)$ or $(5)$ give $P(E)=0.0024787522$, in good agreement with Henry's results.

Final update:
There's really no need of using probability, we can directly apply the approximation $\binom{n-x}{k}/\binom{n}{k}\approx (1-\frac{k}{n-x})^x \approx \exp( -\frac{x \,k}{n-x})$ to Henry's exact result. Here, we again assume $n \to \infty$, $k/n \to 0$ and fixed $M$.
$$\begin{align}
P &= \prod_{i=1}^{M-1} \dfrac{{N - ik \choose k}}{{N \choose k}}\\ &\approx  \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^{M-1} -\frac{i \,k^2}{n-ik}\right)
\\
&\approx  \exp  \left(-\frac{k^2}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{M-1} i ( 1 + i \frac{k}{n})\right) \\
&= \exp  \left(-\frac{k^2}{n} \frac{M(M-1)}{2}\left( 1 + \frac{k}{n}\frac{2M-1}{3}\right) \right) \tag 7
\end{align} 
$$
This coincides, to first order, with $(3)$ or $(5)$, and it gives better approximation for not so big $n$. For example the relative errors for $n=900$, $k=30$, $M=4$:
           P        rel err 
exact 0.00173804
(3)   0.00201548     15.9%
(5)   0.00247875     42.9%
(7)   0.00155440    -10.6%


This is an interesting probability problem with very large values for $N$, $k$, and the number of sets $M$. Your reasoning and approach are quite close to the right track, and I’ll walk through the details of why it works and examine the error term more closely.
Key Insights and Approximation Justification

Total Ways to Choose Sets:
The total number of ways to select $M$ sets, each containing $k$ elements chosen from $N$ without replacement, is indeed:
$\displaystyle
   \left( \binom{N}{k} \right)^M
   $

Non-overlapping Sets:
To ensure that each set is disjoint from the others, each subsequent set must be chosen from the remaining $N - i \cdot k$ elements, where $i$ is the index of the set. Therefore, the number of ways to select $M$ disjoint sets is:
$\displaystyle
   \prod_{i=0}^{M-1} \binom{N - i \cdot k}{k}
   $

Probability Expression:
The probability $P$ that $M$ sets are chosen such that all are disjoint is then:
$\displaystyle
   P = \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{M-1} \binom{N - i \cdot k}{k}}{\left( \binom{N}{k} \right)^M}
   $


Simplification of the Terms
The binomial coefficient $\binom{N - i \cdot k}{k}$ for each $i$ is approximately:
$\displaystyle 
\binom{N - i \cdot k}{k} \approx \frac{(N - i \cdot k)^k}{k!}
$
Therefore, the numerator can be approximated by:
$\displaystyle
\prod_{i=0}^{M-1} \frac{(N - i \cdot k)^k}{k!} = \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{M-1} (N - i \cdot k)^k}{(k!)^M}
$
Similarly, the denominator becomes:
$\displaystyle
\left( \binom{N}{k} \right)^M \approx \frac{N^{M \cdot k}}{(k!)^M}
$
Simplified Probability Expression
Now, we can simplify $P$ as:
$\displaystyle 
P \approx \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{M-1} (N - i \cdot k)^k}{N^{M \cdot k}}
$
Expanding this product in the numerator:
$\displaystyle
\prod_{i=0}^{M-1} (N - i \cdot k)^k = N^{M \cdot k} \prod_{i=0}^{M-1} \left(1 - \frac{i \cdot k}{N}\right)^k
$
Using the approximation $(1 - x) \approx e^{-x}$ for small $x$, we get:
$\displaystyle
\prod_{i=0}^{M-1} \left(1 - \frac{i \cdot k}{N}\right)^k \approx e^{-\sum_{i=0}^{M-1} \frac{i \cdot k^2}{N}}
$
The sum $ \sum_{i=0}^{M-1} i $ is approximately $ \frac{M^2}{2} $, so:
$\displaystyle
\sum_{i=0}^{M-1} \frac{i \cdot k^2}{N} \approx \frac{M^2 k^2}{2N}
$
Thus:
$\displaystyle
P \approx e^{-\frac{M^2 k^2}{2N}}
$
Conclusion and Error Term
For $ N = O(10^{20}), k = O(10^{10})$, and $M = O(1)$, the exponent $\frac{M^2 k^2}{2N}$ is indeed very small. Specifically, since $\frac{k^2}{N} = O(10^{-10})$, we get:
$\displaystyle
P \approx e^{-\text{small term}} \approx 1 - \text{small term}
$
which means $P$ is extremely close to 1, and the probability of having no overlaps is approximately 1 with an error of $O(10^{-10})$, as you stated.
Final Answer
Yes, your approximation is correct, and the error term $O\left(\frac{k^2}{N}\right) = O(10^{-10})$ is indeed very small.

Welcome to MSE! I edited your post to be more suitable for this site. Sorry for the interruption, but if you notice something different from your original intention, please edit your post using the 'Edit' button at the center of the 5 buttons beneath it.
